# How to enable kiosk mode with non-launcher app?

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, android-management-api

In my custom [DPC app](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/build-dpc) (which is configured as device owner), I would like to set a third-party app in kiosk mode.

I did some tests with [DevicePolicyManager.addPersistentPreferredActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#addPersistentPreferredActivity(android.content.ComponentName,%2520android.content.IntentFilter,%2520android.content.ComponentName)) but it seems to only work if the target app is a launcher, i.e if the provided component is an activity that supports the HOME and DEFAULT intent categories. But I need it to work with any app.

Google DPC [Android Device Policy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc) can make it, as explained in ["Apps that don't support lock task mode"](https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices#kiosk-apps) by providing only the package name (not the full activity component name) in the `persistentPreferredActivities` section of the policy. Therefore I assume that it is possible to do it in my DPC, but how ?

Comment: Hi, did you solve it?

Comment: @isthemartin The DPC is now the default launcher and it is responsible for launching the other app when starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have found is to set the DPC as the default launcher, and auto-start the third-party app from the DPC.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, there is no official way to lock an app into kiosk mode with a policy when `lock mode` is not supported.

the `addPersistentPreferredActivity()` method only sets the default handler for these intents but they can also be overridden.